How to Implement a Local VPN in Android for Content Filtering Without Server Dependency?
I'm working on an Android application that requires creating a local VPN to route all device network traffic for content filtering purposes. Instead of using a remote VPN server, my goal is to develop a VPN service that operates locally on the device.
Here are the key aspects of what I'm trying to achieve:

Local VPN Setup:

Create and manage a VPN service locally on the Android device using Kotlin.
Configure VPN settings such as IP address, routing, and DNS servers.


Content Filtering:

Intercept and filter HTTP traffic routed through the local VPN.
Implement filtering rules to block or allow specific content.


VPN Lifecycle Management:

Start and stop the VPN service based on user interactions (i.e., "Enable VPN" and "Disable VPN" buttons).



Current Implementation:
Here is a simplified version of my MainActivity and MyVpnService:
MainActivity:
package com.example.adblocker

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.IntentFilter
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.net.VpnService
import android.os.Bundle
import android.preference.PreferenceManager
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.items
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.example.adblocker.ui.theme.AdblockerTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private var websiteList by mutableStateOf(emptyList<String>())
    private lateinit var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences

    private val websiteReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
            val newWebsites = intent?.getStringArrayListExtra("websiteList") ?: emptyList()
            websiteList = newWebsites
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
        setContent {
            AdblockerTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    VpnScreen(
                        websiteList = websiteList,
                        onStartVpnClick = { startVpnService() },
                        onStopVpnClick = { stopVpnService() }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
        registerReceiver(websiteReceiver, IntentFilter("com.example.adblocker.UPDATE_WEBSITES"))
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        unregisterReceiver(websiteReceiver)
    }

    private fun startVpnService() {
        val vpnIntent = VpnService.prepare(this)
        if (vpnIntent != null) {
            startActivityForResult(vpnIntent, 0)
        } else {
            onActivityResult(0, RESULT_OK, null)
        }
    }

    private fun stopVpnService() {
        val intent = Intent(this, MyVpnService::class.java)
        stopService(intent)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            val intent = Intent(this, MyVpnService::class.java)
            startService(intent)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun VpnScreen(
    websiteList: List<String>,
    onStartVpnClick: () -> Unit,
    onStopVpnClick: () -> Unit
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(16.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "AdBlocker VPN",
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleLarge,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 20.dp)
        )
        Button(onClick = onStartVpnClick) {
            Text(text = "Enable VPN")
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
        Button(onClick = onStopVpnClick) {
            Text(text = "Disable VPN")
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .weight(1f)
        ) {
            items(websiteList) { website ->
                Text(text = website)
            }
        }
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun VpnScreenPreview() {
    AdblockerTheme {
        VpnScreen(websiteList = emptyList(), onStartVpnClick = {}, onStopVpnClick = {})
    }
}

MyVpnService:
package com.example.adblocker

import android.net.VpnService
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor
import android.util.Log

class MyVpnService : VpnService() {
    private var vpnInterface: ParcelFileDescriptor? = null

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        startVpn()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        vpnInterface?.close()
    }

    private fun startVpn() {
        try {
            val builder = Builder()
            builder.setSession("My VPN Service")
            builder.addAddress("10.0.0.2", 24)   // Local VPN IP address
            builder.addRoute("0.0.0.0", 0)       // Route all traffic through the VPN
            builder.addDnsServer("8.8.8.8")      // DNS server for name resolution
            builder.addDnsServer("8.8.4.4")      // Optional additional DNS server

            vpnInterface = builder.establish()
            Log.d("MyVpnService", "VPN started with address 10.0.0.2")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            Log.e("MyVpnService", "Error starting VPN: ${e.message}")
        }
    }
}

AndroidmanifestXml:
`
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Adblocker">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name=".MyVpnService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_VPN_SERVICE"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.VpnService"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.faketouch" android:required="false" />


`
Problem:
After starting the VPN service, the network connectivity is not working, and I am seeing an error indicating "no internet connection." The VPN service starts, but the device cannot access the internet or route traffic correctly. enter image description here
Question:
How can I resolve the issue of network connectivity not working after starting the VPN service? Are there specific configurations or additional steps required to ensure that the VPN correctly routes and filters network traffic on the device?

Feel free to adjust or expand on the question as needed.
Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Verified VPN configuration (IP address, routing, and DNS).
Checked logs for errors related to VPN setup.
Tested minimal VPN configurations to isolate issues.
Ensured device network setup is correct when the VPN is active.

